# forEach is not a function uploading multiple images to cloudinary

Tags: javascript, vue.js, upload, vuejs2, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images to cloudinary from my Vue2JS front. I already created function which upload correctly single image but I have problem with uploading multiple images in forEach loop.

```
upload(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    let file = evt.target.files;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file[0]);
    formData.append('upload_preset', this.cloudinary.uploadPreset);
    axios.post(this.cloudinary.url, formData)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.secure_url);
            this.offerData.thumbnail = res.data.secure_url;
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
},
uploadImages(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    const formData = new FormData();
    evt.forEach(evt.target.files, function (file) {
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('upload_preset', this.cloudinary.uploadPreset);
        axios.post(this.cloudinary.url, formData)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data.secure_url);
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            });
    })
},
```

upload function is working correctly as I said. Later on I will combine those two functions into one but just for development I separate it because this second one function which is uploadImages is not working correctly..

`evt.target.files` is:

[image: alt]

(click to make it bigger)

and error which show in console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: evt.forEach is not a function

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: I removed the comment, because I realised what you're doing - however, a FileList (much like an Event) doesn't have `forEach` either ... perhaps `[].forEach.call(evt.target.files, function(file) { .... }` ?

Comment: what in the world is `evt.forEach(evt.target.files, function (file) {`?? There is no forEach on it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event unless vue does something weird I do not know about.

Comment: Of course, then you have the issue that you'll add each file to a single `formData` - so if there's 3 files, the first POST will have 1, second will have 1 and 2, and the 3rd will have 1, 2 and 3 in the formdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to execute a `forEach` method on an `Event`, but Event does not have a forEach method

Even if you tried to do it with `evt.target.files`, that's a `FileList`, and does not have a `forEach` method

Borrowed from AJD's answer, with the following changes

- use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys` - never interested in the key, so this removes the need to `let file = evt.target.files[key]`
- fix the possible issue with `formData` - you keep adding to a single one in the loop - I'd rather create a new one for each loop
- fix `this` being "lost" (by using arrow function)

The code then becomes

```
uploadImages(evt) {
    Object.values(evt.target.files).forEach(file => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('upload_preset', this.cloudinary.uploadPreset);
        axios.post(this.cloudinary.url, formData)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data.secure_url);
            }, err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: And this solution also work for single image thanks:)

Comment: @BT101 - there's no issue with uploading multiple images "at once"? If so, I can suggest a solution to only upload one image at a time

Comment: I don't understand, it is not uploading "at once" because it upload in loop one by one at the end of this script work I have 2 or more links to images in console. It works correctly

Comment: nevermind @BT101 - some API's don't like to be "bombarded" with multiple requests from the one client at once

Answer (score 2):

forEach is a function of the Javascript Array. That looks like an object of type FileList.

You can iterate over object keys with a for loop, or by using Object.keys() to create an array of its keys and then iterate over those.

For example:

```
uploadImages(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(evt.target.files).forEach(function(key){
        let file = evt.target.files[key];
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('upload_preset', this.cloudinary.uploadPreset);
        axios.post(this.cloudinary.url, formData)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data.secure_url);
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: why not `Object.values(evt.target.files).forEach(function(file) {` :p

Comment: Is it some different between those two?

Comment: Is there some nice option for passing this scope into .forEach? Because now I need to additionally declare that = this outside of .forEach to have access

Comment: you won't need the `let file = evt.target.files[key];` ... this still may have an issue ... what happens if you keep appending to the one formData between uploads?

Comment: use arrow notation - see my answer